# react - not able to update state in input value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am learning react and I want to create a simple form where the input value changes and updates once the user types it in. I have this code where the input value updates the state when it is being typed, but when I press enter, the old state returns. I did lots of googling but can't seem to make it work. I have tried it with a submit button in the form, but that doesn't make a difference. I would like to make it work without a submit button as in the value changes and updates onChange only. What am I not seeing?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
 
  const [value, setValue] = useState('John');
  
  const handleInputOnChange =(e)=> {
    setValue(e.target.value)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
           <label>
               Name:
               <input value={value} onChange={handleInputOnChange}/>
           </label>
       </form>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: In many browsers pressing enter in a form will automatically submit the form.

Comment: If you don't actually need a `<form>`, don't use one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because of the `form` tag. Whenever you hit enter the `form` will be submitted by default and the value of the `input` will be back to its initial value.

There are two ways you can stop this from happening.

1.) Remove the `form` tag from your `App` component.

2.) Add `onSubmit` function to the `form` to handle the `form` when it is submitted like below.

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>...</form>
```

And the function to handle the `form` is as below:

```
const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

The `preventDefault` method will stop the `default` behavior of the `form` when it is submitted.

Comment: Could even make that submit handler inline since it's so small... `onSubmit={e=>e.preventDefault()}`

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It worked and I learned something new!

Comment: Your most welcome :)